Why can't I connect to the server via the Socket library in Python?
I started learning Socket in Python. Moreover, when connecting to the server (which was running on my computer), everything worked, but when my friend tried to connect to me from another PC, the client simply could not detect the server and connect to it.
I wrote client and server:
#client
import socket

host = ""
port = 1234

client  = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


client.settimeout(10)
client.connect((host, port))
client.settimeout(None)
print("connected")
client.send(("Hellow world!").encode())

#server
import socket

host = ""
port = 1234

server  = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(10)

print("server launched")
while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    print("Connect from", addr)

    data = conn.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode()
    print(data)

A friend tried to start the client, but for some reason, the client can't connect to the server.

Probably your computer blocks connections from other computers on port 1234.

Or your friend tried something stupid like connecting to port 1234 on localhost; this obviously only works when localhost is where the server is running.

You, as a server without a client, must connect first, while your friend, as a client, starts connecting to the server (you). Both must be same port.

this isn't really related to sockets in python, it's a network problem. Either your firewall is blocking the connection, or your NAT is, or there is no route between your two computers, or the IP address / hostname you are using is wrong… Without more info on the network config, it is going to be hard to solve this


set the host on the client to your host

Get your ip address
on windows use ipconfig, on linux use ip a
and give the ip to the client so it knows where to connect to
#client
import socket

host = "" # <- this needs to be set to the ip of your device
port = 1234

client  = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


client.settimeout(10)
client.connect((host, port))
client.settimeout(None)
print("connected")
client.send(("Hellow world!").encode())


check if your friend's computer can reach your computer

Make sure your computer is in the same network as your friends computer, or in the case that you aren't, that you have set up port-forwarding on your router. Note that if you are using port forwarding you don't need your devices ip, but the ip of the router.

check your firewall settings

Make sure the port you are using (1234) is open and python has to permission to use this port. Unfortunately most antivirus/firewall programs each have their own way of setting this up so you are going have to look this one up yourself.
or
BAD IDEA: disable your firewall temporarily, this can also be helpful to see if it's an issue with your firewall settings.
